# rqt_reconfigure unable to resize column in Kinetic [solved]

Tags: ros, rqt-reconfigure, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

When I launch (with ROS Kinetic)

```
rosrun rqt_reconfigure rqt_reconfigure
```

I can't resize the column where the reconfigure server names appear.

[image: image description]

It's annoying when there are many levels in a tree, like when launching openni2_launch for example, then it's impossible to read no matter how I resize the window.

Anybody has the same issue, is it a normal behavior ?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/289775/rqt_reconfigure-unable-to-resize-column-in-kinetic-%5Bsolved%5D/) by [Cyril Jourdan](https://answers.ros.org/users/4040/cyril-jourdan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 157 on 2018-04-26

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2018-04-26**:
More input needed, e.g. screenshot of the GUI where we can see the problem you're talking about.

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2018-04-26**:
Besides, if any of existing PRs (e.g. [this](https://github.com/ros-visualization/rqt_reconfigure/pull/7), [this](https://github.com/ros-visualization/rqt_reconfigure/pull/14)) are related then you can chime in there.

**Comment by [Cyril Jourdan](https://answers.ros.org/users/4040/cyril-jourdan/) on 2018-04-26**:
I've updated with the screenshot. I'll comment on github as well, thanks for the links.

**Comment by [Cyril Jourdan](https://answers.ros.org/users/4040/cyril-jourdan/) on 2018-04-26**:
In fact the issue has been solved, my package was a bit old, after an upgrade of ros-kinetic-rqt-reconfigure, the issue is solved !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To solve that, just upgrade your package:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-rqt-reconfigure
```

---

Originally posted by [Cyril Jourdan](https://answers.ros.org/users/4040/cyril-jourdan/) with karma: 157 on 2018-04-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0